# What does $^ in gnu make mean?

Tags: gnu-make

I am translating GNU makefile to NMake makefile.
I came across such construction in GNU Makefile:

```
DEP1 = dependencyA1.c dependencyA1.c
DEP2 = dependencyB1.c dependencyB2.c

libABC.a: $(DEP1) $(DEP2)
    $(ARCHIVE)  libABC.a $^    #**what this does?**
```

I quite often write GNU Makefiles, but it is first time I found such instruction. Could someone more experienced explain what it does?

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables